# How to use ContentNegotiatingViewResolver for either text/html or application/json?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, servlets

I created a RESTful service with SpringMVC. There are a bunch of tutorials and it worked fine. Now, the app should respond with application/json or RESTful in some cases, and with normal ViewResolvers and text/html (.jsp) in other cases.
I thought a ContentNegotiatingViewResolver would apply best in this case (is it?).

My question now: What view/servlet/* should I use to display json (REST result) directly? This is my servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.atrioom" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                <property name="viewClass"
                    value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
    <property name="prefix"> <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value> </property> <property 
    name="suffix"> <value>.jsp</value> </property> </bean -->
```

For every request now, the servlet looks for a `.jsp` file to display. That is for `text/html` and for `application/json`. The way I want it to behave is to serve a view (jsp) when `text/html` is called, and a direct json output when `application/json` is called.
I had this working when I made a REST-only service. No jsp file was required, the application just directly returned the data json-formatted.
I don't know how to tell the Negotiater what to do in the json case. Is there a special REST Resolver that I need? Can somebody shed some light, please?

Kind regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in your view resolver property.
Consult API [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html)

Comment: Other than that MessageConverter my servlet.xml looks good? Thanks for your answer btw!